# Back button rewrite to redirect back to new location

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a situation where I want to rewrite the back history
for example I am at my page:

```
http://mysite.example.com
```

and I go to another page by clicking a link

```
http://mysite.example.com/sports
```

Now when I click back, I want to be able to have a parameter appended to the URL
so by click back the users will actually need to go here
http://mysite.example.com?backfrom=sports
Now I know that html5 has apis that I can use but for some reason its not for me
on my http://mysite.example.com/sports JavaScript I add this

```
<script>
 history.replaceState(null, null, "?backfrom=sports");
</script>
```

but that just change the url and when I click the back button, I still end up at
`http://mysite.example.com`

What can I do to change the history in a way that when I click back button it includes the parameters.
I think there is `onpopstate` but I am not sure how can I make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think of a possible solution which could be to add the script in the index page of http://mysite.example.com like this

```
<script>

$('body').on('click','.mylink', changehistory);

function changehistory(){

  history.pushState(null,null,'?backfrom=sports');

}

</script>
```

this will fake the URL and now when I click back from

http://mysite.example.com/sports

I get back to

```
 http://mysite.example.com?backfrom=sports
```

Thought I would share